# Infinite loop caused by ordering error Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

Faced an issue in Django 3.1.10. It used to work fine for me, however, when deploying the database, when I execute the Payments.objects.all() request, I get the following error.

```
Infinite loop caused by ordering. ['File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/app/bot/assets/BaseRequests.py", line 42, in handle   
await self.__handler(callback, path_args, bot, user)', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/app/bot/commands/subscription.py", line 291, in _    

await subscription_cmd(bot=bot, callback=callback, user=user, path_args=path_args)', 
'  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/app/bot/commands/subscription.py", line 227, in subscription_cmd\n    for num, pd in enumerate(payment_data, start=1):
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__\n    self._fetch_all()
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all    
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__    
results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1162, in execute_sql    
sql, params = self.as_sql()
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 513, in as_sql
extra_select, order_by, group_by = self.pre_sql_setup()
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 56, in pre_sql_setup    
order_by = self.get_order_by()
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 356, in get_order_by    order_by.extend(self.find_ordering_name(
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 765, in find_ordering_name    results.extend(self.find_ordering_name(item, opts, alias,
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 765, in find_ordering_name    results.extend(self.find_ordering_name(item, opts, alias,
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 765, in find_ordering_name    results.extend(self.find_ordering_name(item, opts, alias,
', '  File "/Users/wezzyofficial/PycharmProjects/subscriber_tgbot/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 755, in find_ordering_name    
raise FieldError(\'Infinite loop caused by ordering.\')']
```

The model itself from the models.py:

```
class Payments(models.Model):
    rate = models.ForeignKey(Rates, help_text='Rate', blank=True, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rate_Payments')

    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupons, help_text='Coupon', blank=True, null=True,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='coupon_Payments')

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, help_text='User', blank=True, null=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_Payments')

    cost = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=32, decimal_places=2, help_text='Цена')

    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Paid')
    renewal = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Renewal')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Payments"
        verbose_name_plural = "Payments"
        ordering = ("id", "rate", "coupon", "user", "cost", "paid", "renewal")


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} | {self.rate} | {self.coupon} | {self.user} | {self.paid} | {self.renewal}'
```

I have already changed the database from sqlite3 to postgresql but it didn't help.

Comment: If you use `ordering = ("id", "rate", "coupon", "user", "cost", "paid", "renewal")` the other fields are quite useless, since two different `Payments` records will always have a different `id`. You thus can rewrite this to `ordering = ("id",)`

Comment: I'm going to say this is not the model ordering, but whatever is being done in `BaseRequests.py` in particular `await subscription_cmd(...`. Whenever I see `await` and a database I expect the worse.